# How do I make sure my wrapper does not cover my footer?

Tags: footer

My footer seems to be covered by my wrapper so it doesn't extend all the way across the page. How can I fix this?

Comment: you didn't provide any codes to us.So we can't really see your codes.Please updates the post with your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that with the CSS:

```
#class footer{position: fixed;}
```

that should solve you problem